# css border-color: -moz-use-text-color not working in chrome

Tags: html, css

i have the below css for a table underand its not working in chrome and firefox as expected.  instead shows darker border colors. How can i resolve this? any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Below is complete css:

```
TABLE {
    BORDER-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px; 
    BORDER-TOP: 0px; 
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px; 
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    MARGIN: 0px;  
    BORDER-LEFT: 0px; 
    PADDING-TOP: 0px;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px
}

<table width="760" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="2"cellpadding="2" bordercolor="#CCCCCC" style="margin:0 auto;">
<tr>
<td width="100%" align="center" colspan="2" style="margin: 0px auto;">
//...code...//
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Added the code and css for table. find below css for td.

```
TD {
    font-family: tahoma,sans-serif;
    font-size: 80.5%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here in IE8 all the border use default color where as in ff and chrome border color is black. Please help!

Comment: Firstly wheres the rest of your code? and secondly how is it supposed to work?

Comment: the "complete css" doesnt contain any border-color definitions?

Comment: Your `border-right` etc. properties must list width, color and style. And you can just say `padding: 0`.

Comment: The `border`, `cellspacing` etc. attributes on the `table` element are deprecated, and should not be used. Also, your `</td>` and `</tr>` closing tags are in the wrong order. Where are you using `-moz-use-text-color`? In any case, you should be using `currentColor` instead.

Comment: @olly_uk no there is no border-color defination in my css, but in ff using firebug shows the css  border-color: -moz-use-text-color;

Comment: -moz <--- Mozilla -webkit <--- google chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite the jumble of styles, inline styles and deprecated presentational attributes (from HTML 4.01) crowding your markup (and quite possibly giving the browser a set of conflicting, confusing instructions).

To start with, we should tidy everything up, by:

1) Removing all inline styles and presentational attributes (except `colspan`) from the markup and placing it in the CSS;

2) Tidying up the CSS, itself.

This gives us:

**CSS:**

```
table {
width: 760px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
width: 100%;
margin: 2px auto;
padding: 2px;
font-family: tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 80.5%;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
//...code...//
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now the `table` `border-color` should be showing as `#ccc` in every browser.